# How many different beads can be manufactured with 3 colors?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The question is the following: "A bracelet is made from five beads mounted on a circular wire. How many different brecelets can we manufacture if we have red blue and yellow beads at our disposal."

I know that I have to use the counting theorem, but i can't figure out the details, I do think that the group is isomorphic to $D_5$ but I am not entirely sure about that

Edit: If the group is isomorphic to $D_5$ there are the conjugation classes $\{e\}, \{r,r^4\}, \{r^2,r^3\}, \{s,rs,r^2s,r^3s,r^4s\}$, which each (respectively) leave this amount fixed $3^5,3,3,3^3$ which acording to the orbit counting theorem should be $\frac{1}{10}(3^5 + 3 \cdot2+ 3\cdot2+3^3\cdot 5) = 39$. Could somebody correct me if I'm wrong (altough this is the same awnser as Henry's).

Comment: Presumably if it is a bracelet (rather than a necklace) you can turn it over as well as rotate it

Comment: So it would be isomorphic to $D_5$?

Comment: Your solution is correct, that's how it can done with Burnside's Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess with rotation and turning over, the patterns could be:

- xxxxx $3$ ways
- xxxxy $6$ ways
- xxxyy $6$ ways
- xxyxy $6$ ways
- xxxyz $3$ ways
- xxyxz $3$ ways
- xxyyz $3$ ways
- xyxyz $3$ ways
- xyyxz $6$ ways

making $39$, but I may have missed some

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you got these ways, because that could be really helpful for solving similar problems.

Comment: It was an attempt at a systematic count, and then some more.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html gives a formula for "free necklaces" http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/Necklace/NumberedEquation2.gif where here $n=5$ and $a=3$

Comment: I actually was hoping for a explanation using the orbit counting theorem but thanks anyway.